# How to get a specific method from an implementation of an interface type, which the interface doesn't provide?

Tags: java

I use a common interface which doesn't provide a method from an implementation class. I don't want to instantiate the concrete implementation, but still need to use this method.

**Concrete question: How to make the `specialMethod()` available?**

Interface:

```
public interface Filter {
    void commonMethod();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class IpFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void commonMethod() {
    }

    public void specialMethod() {
    }
}
```

Container class:

```
public class Manager {

    private final Filter filter = new IpFilter();

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return this.filter;
    }
}
```

Caller class:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Manager manager = new Manager();
    manager.getFilter().commonMethod();
    manager.getFilter().specialMethod(); // METHOD NOT AVAILABLE
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to call a method that only exists for `IpFilter`s when you have a `Filter`?

Comment: This is not possible.  What happens when the `specialMethod()` refers to an instance variable in the concrete class?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Because the `IpFilter` has capabilities which other `Filter` implementations don't have.

Comment: But how do you know you have an `IpFilter` and not some other kind of `Filter`?

Comment: @JimGarrison What about generics?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I assume this will need generics, but I'm too stupid to use them :D

Comment: Generics have nothing to do with this.  There has to be a concrete class instance in existence at the point where you want to call `specialMethod()`.  If you can prove (i.e. with instanceof) it's the right class then you can downcast to `IpFilter` and call the method.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks. That sounds like a solution, but I have hoped to avoid that. Thought there would be some generics magic.

Comment: I've posted this as an answer, with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a concrete class instance in existence at the point where you want to call `specialMethod()`. If you can prove (i.e. with `instanceof`) it's the right class then you can downcast to `IpFilter` and call the method.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Manager manager = new Manager();
    Filter f = manager.getFilter();
    f.commonMethod(); 
    if (f instanceof IpFilter)
    {
        ((IpFilter) f).specialMethod();
    }
    ...
}
```

HOWEVER, this is code smell and should be avoided.

DOUBLE-HOWEVER sometimes the sausage-making is not pretty and this is the only way to accomplish something if you have to work within a legacy system that cannot be redesigned to not smell so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class Manager {

    private final Filter filter = new IpFilter();

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return this.filter;
    }
}
```

to

```
public class Manager {

    private final IpFilter filter = new IpFilter();

    public IpFilter getFilter() {
        return this.filter;
    }
}
```

The specialMethod() doesn't show up because the object your trying to invoke the method on is a "Filter", and Filter does not define specialMethod. Only IpFilter does.